# How can I add a VS 2010 .Net 4.0 build agent to TFS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, .net-4.0, tfsbuild

My company has two development teams using TFS 2008.  My team would like to migrate our .Net 3.5 app to the .Net 4.0 framework, but the company is not ready to upgrade TFS to TFS 2010.

Can we still use TFS 2008's team build system but with a Visual Studio 2010 solution/project structure that targets the .Net 4.0 framework?

I am thinking we would need to add a new build agent to TFS 2008 that would have VS 2010 installed.  But I am not finding any information on how to do this.

Is this possible?  Are there any articles explaining how to do this?

Comment: You definitely wont find documentation about tha at this point - the request per se is not without sense, but a rare occasion, and VS 2010 is not that widely used yet. I personally dont see a reason why a build system should not be able to somehow target 4.0 - it is msbuild, after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google and Bing haven't found this nugget yet, but William Bartholomew at Microsoft has explained how to do this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/willbar/archive/2009/11/01/building-net-4-0-applications-using-team-build-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [it is not possible to use a TFS2010 build agent with a TFS2008 server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/c5ed30f9-b660-4b7a-bc1a-5caaf43c3690). (what you asked for)

You can however, [use the TFS2008 build agent to build .Net 4.0 / VS2010 solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2009/11/01/building-net-4-0-applications-using-team-build-2008.aspx) (this what the accepted answer is linking to).  This gets the job done, but you don't get the improved build engine (workflow) and reporting of 2010, but you can't use that anyway with your 2008 server!

This really is the only way to go until you can migrate to a TFS2010 server.