# TFS Build Agent Issue?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a scenario like that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463285/how-can-i-add-a-vs-2010-net-4-0-build-agent-to-tfs-2008).

Unfortunately, the solution doesn't work for me. My build project has a folder named bin where all external DLLs are stored and referenced. The problem I'm having is this: the bin folder is created under the working folder when queueing a build, but it's empty and consequently the build fails.

Any idea why this would happen and how to go about fixing it?

**EDIT** - Everything is checked into TFS and the build definition workspace is set to two levels above the bin folder. The working folder above refers to the build agent working folder (as opposed to the build definition workspace).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641580/not-all-tfs-build-type-files-are-getting-copied

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the linked question has to do with your bin folder problem description.

But if you have stored binary dependencies in your bin folder (bad practice), you just need to make sure that they are checked into TFS, and the build definition workspace mapping includes that bin folder (or one of it's higher level ancestors), and the Get that happens at the start of the build process should download whatever is in TFS to the build agent.

It's important to note that the TFS Build by default doesn't output into the bin/debug folder, but that shouldn't matter for picking up references.

Comment: Everything is checked into TFS and the build definition workspace is set to two levels above the bin folder. I should note that this setup works well in the main trunk and all other branches. This problematic branch is different from the rest because it uses .NET 4.0 and VS2010 (hence the linked question).